# Quartz JobScheduler Delete Triggers on Exception in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have many jobs in quartz, in spring boot. these methods have @Transactional annotation and I can't use a try-catch block. when I run the project, after a while, the scheduler fails and all data in the QRTZ_TRIGGERS table remove and all the jobs cancel and I have to restart the application to start jobs again. how can I avoid deleting these data?

Comment: Not sure if `storeDurably(boolean jobDurability)` in `JobBuilder` can help?

Comment: This cannot help me. What I would like to know is under what scenario this happens.